# C++ std::memory_order_relaxed confusion

Tags: c++, multithreading, synchronization, atomic

I was reading [this article](https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/Atomic/GCCMM/AtomicSync) from GCC Wiki about C++ memory barriers (and its awesome).
It was pretty straightforward until I got to this point:

*The opposite approach is std::memory_order_relaxed. This model allows for much less synchronization by removing the happens-before restrictions. These types of atomic operations can also have various optimizations performed on them, such as dead store removal and commoning.
So in the earlier example:*

```
-Thread 1-
y.store (20, memory_order_relaxed)
x.store (10, memory_order_relaxed)

-Thread 2-
if (x.load (memory_order_relaxed) == 10)
  {
    assert (y.load(memory_order_relaxed) == 20) /* assert A */
    y.store (10, memory_order_relaxed)
  }

-Thread 3-
if (y.load (memory_order_relaxed) == 10)
  assert (x.load(memory_order_relaxed) == 10) /* assert B */
```

*Since threads don't need to be synchronized across the system, either assert in this example can actually FAIL.*

Ok, this is straightforward as well, lets carry on..

```
-Thread 1-
x.store (1, memory_order_relaxed)
x.store (2, memory_order_relaxed)

-Thread 2-
y = x.load (memory_order_relaxed)
z = x.load (memory_order_relaxed)
assert (y <= z)
```

*The assert cannot fail. Once the store of 2 is seen by thread 2, it can no longer see the value 1. This prevents coalescing relaxed loads of one variable across relaxed loads of a different reference that might alias.*

**This is what confused me, why y cannot load the value 2 and z load the value 1 (and cause assertion to fail), since the ordering is not synchronized in thread 1?**

Comment: The missing paragraph from the link says: "*The only ordering imposed is that once a value for a variable from thread 1 is observed in thread 2, thread 2 can not see an “earlier” value for that variable from thread 1*".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Relaxed ordering is relative to the ordering of operations with regard to *other memory accesses*, not ordering relative to the atomic being relax-modified. In your first case, the fact that you can see 10 in `x` doesn't mean anything with regard to the value of `y`. And vice-versa.

But your second case is different, because it's affecting the same atomic object.

[[intro.races]/10](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/intro.races#10) tells us that, within a thread, if one operation is sequenced before another, then that operation "happens before" the other. And [[intro.races]/14-17 outline the following behavior with regard to atomics](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/intro.races#14):

> The four preceding coherence requirements effectively disallow compiler reordering of atomic operations to a single object, even if both operations are relaxed loads.

And that's what you have here. All of the modifications are happening to the same object, so they must happen in *some* order. Even if that order cannot be determined exactly, the order must respect the "happens before" relationships of the code.

Thread 1's two operations are ordered by a "happens before" relationship. And Thread 2's operations are themselves ordered by a "happens before" relationship.

Since they're all acting on the same atomic object, if `y` gets the value of 2, then it must have "happened after" `x` was set to 2. So the order of access for `x` must have been "x = 1, x = 2, read x". And since the last read of `x` happens after the first read of `x`, the value it gets cannot be 1.